# How to get around subshell problem with sudo and file permissions

Tags: linux, sudo, environment, subshell, sudoers

I have a specific problem.  Here's a simplified example:

File `/opt/test` is owned by root.  Has file permissions of `700`.

I need to `cp /opt/test /home/user/`.

So I need this exact command set in my sudoers file.  I can't open up permissions to any other command.

But if I put this as a `NOPASSWD` command in `/etc/sudoers` it doesn't work because my user does not have permissions to see `/opt/test` before it `su`'s to the root user (`sudo` is 'globbing' or whatever the file paths before it runs an `su` to `root`).

How can I invoke this command in a subshell or something so that I can get the exact command laid out in `/etc/sudoers`?  Putting the command in a script and then laying out the path to the script in `sudoers` fails (permissions).  I think I need to invoke a subshell of sorts, but don't know how to lay that out in `sudoers`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having. Can you copy and paste terminal output showing what's happening, and show us exactly what you entered into `/etc/sudoers`? Your diagnosis doesn't really make sense to me: "...my user does not have permission to see `/opt/test` before it `su`'s to the root user". If you do it right and grant access to `cp /opt/test /home/user/` then `sudo cp /opt/test /home/user/` will work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming.

Comment: Sure.  If I put `cp /opt/test /home/user` in my sudoers file as NOPASSWD for my user, it fails and tells me permission denied. I don't know if this is because sudo is first trying to test and make sure the files exist before it changes UID and then passes the files to `cp`, but I think that is what is happening.  Basically, similar to what is explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/918333/why-cant-sudo-cp-find-the-files

Comment: The question you linked has globs `*`. Yours doesn't, so the answer doesn't apply.

Comment: So we dug and dug and figured out the problem(s).  First, the 'to' destination was a network mount with nosuid set, and that was causing problems with sudo.  Second, SELinux contexts were set on the 'from', & it was blocking access to stat the files for reading.  So if anyone else has a similar problem, try checking your mount permissions and SELinux policies.